# They are pressurised by me.
They have been pressured by me

Tags: word-usage

They are pressurised by me.
They have been pressured by me.

Please explain I don't know the meaning or usage

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  I had to lookup the meaning of pressurised to be sure, but they can both mean to attempt to persuade or coerce.

The difference being that only pressurised can also mean to produce or maintain raised pressure artificially in (a gas or its container).  You often hear it used for this meaning, therefore in your context you almost certainly mean to say *pressured* and not pressurised.

Though again, while both are technically right, it is better to stick with pressured as it is a less commonly used second meaning of pressurised.